# Assigning Google Credentials to downloaded keys stored in a storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a python script that access files in a storage bucket on google cloud. I was able to assign the google credentials to the json file (key) stored on my computer.

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=(r"C:\Users\Oladayo\Downloads\production-web-app-338223-02790f690292.json")

I am trying to move the script to be run by google cloud function and I need to reassign the google credentials to the same json file but stored in a storage bucket. I have tried this

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=('gs://storage_service_key/production-web-app-338223-02790f690292.json')

but I keep getting the error below

DefaultCredentialsError: File gs://storage_service_key/production-web-app-338223-02790f690292.json was not found.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, add that environment variable outside your code, and let the [ADC (the default credential detection)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) of the libraries detecting it.

On Cloud Functions, you don't have to add that environment variable. [Cloud Functions' metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) provides the credentials to the libraries and the ADC is also automatically detected.

The great thing is that you don't have to update your code from locally to the cloud, it's totally transparent and it's the libraries that do the job for you!

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am having issues with setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  in an environment variable outside the code. I have tried this on the command prompt set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='Key Path (actual key path)'. Then I ran the code on the Jupyter Notebook first and I get this error 'NotFound: 404 GET storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/field-production-reports/…: The requested project was not found.' Note: I didn't get any output when I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the command prompt. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you –

Comment: If you use a SET you should use Windows. I personally set the environment variable in my system configuration and i restart my computer (if not, there is a lot of chance that some process didn't catch the env var update at system level. Windows stuff....)

Comment: I use windows. but one question. when you set the credentials in an environment variable, can you run the script on your IDE without manually setting the credentials?

Comment: Yes, I do that.

Comment: okay...great. I will keep working around the credentials ish.. I wanted to ensure it work on my IDE before moving it to google cloud function. I will let you know if I succeed in doing that. Thank you so much

Comment: Windows magic!! and despair!!